# Plug to monitor AC energy

Tags: smart-device, measurement-devices

I'm looking for a plug that's able to measure energy consumption (kwh or similar) and that allows reading the data externally from a raspberry pi or similar. The space that I need to control is pretty long and I don't have a WiFi connection, so I was thinking of devices that have LoRa (not LoRaWAN) or some other local long-range protocol.

Thank you

Comment: How about Raspberry Pi w/wifi connecting to tplink kasa via wifi.  Then connect the Pi via your LoRa?  Standard ethernet is 280ft via regular cable plus another 50 feet for wifi.  Fiber optics can certainly run the difference, but connecting that to a Pi, I don't know how to do.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but the distance is longer than that :(